# Problem Making A T-Rex Game Bot Using Selenium and Robot Class

Tags: java, selenium

I have a problem making T-Rex game bot. The code works fine for a few seconds but then the game gets over.
I have used Selenium and The Robot class for this project.

MyCode>>

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, AWTException {
    
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\BHEL\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://trex-runner.com/");
    Robot robo = new Robot();
    robo.mouseMove(460, 520);
    
    while(true) {
        //now i have used for loops to sense the cactus in a square area
        for(int i = 0; i<=10;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<=10;j++) {
                if(robo.getPixelColor(460-i, 520-j).equals(new Color(83,83,83))) {
                        
                    robo.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_UP);
                    robo.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_UP);
                    Thread.sleep(200-j-i);//Stay in the air for a while
                    robo.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
                    robo.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The WebSite url for T-Rex game that i used https://trex-runner.com .
I have seen some other tutorials that did the same thing that i did.
Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be that the coordinates aren't too precise. You could use `System.out.println(MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation());` to get the coordinates of your mouse on your monitor and then change your x and y value to those. That method would get me to 400 points. To get further you have to add more conditions so the robot responds better to the obstacles.
Simple code:

```
while (true) {
        //Got the coordinates from the mouse location ^^^
        if (robo.getPixelColor(580 ,530).equals(new Color(83,83,83))) {

            robo.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
            robo.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
            Thread.sleep(150);//Stay in the air for a while
            robo.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
            robo.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank You for your help now my dinobot is better but there is one more problem when the speed of game increases the dinosaur gets hit I think when the speed increases the capture point should be more far any idea how to do it? (also i have made some changes to my code)

Comment: It is because when the program reads the position of the obstacle the dinosaur is still in the air so it has no time to react. So I think you could try to read all of the obstacles coming and make calculations as to when the Trex has to jump and when to fall with the down arrow.